# Writing shells script to display time in am or pm notation

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a shell script that displays the time in am or pm rather than the way it is shown using date command. I'm not sure how I should go about doing this. I guess for starters, how do I extract the time from the date command to manipulate it? And how do I extract the number for the hour to manipulate it?

Answer (score 13):

What you're looking for is

```
man strftime
```

That stands for string-format-time, which is the format that `date` uses.

So to get the current AM/PM, use the following:

```
date +"%p"
```

or

```
ampm=`date +"%p"`
echo $ampm
```

The hour can be one of several formats (do you want 12 or 24 hour time, leading zero or not?) I'm guessing you want non-leading-zero 12 hour time:

```
date +"%l"
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use below one to print time in AM and PM format up to minutes.

```
echo $(date  +"%I:%M %p")
```

**OutPut**: 09:20 PM

or

```
echo $(date  +"%r")
```

**Output**: 09:20:09 PM

or
   echo $(date +"%I %p")

**Output**: 09 PM

Comment: or just `date  +"%r"`?

Answer (score 4):

> rather than the way it is shown using date command

The [`date`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/timedate.html) command takes a format string. Supplying `%p` will display either "AM" or "PM" according to the given time value, *or the corresponding strings for the current locale*. Noon is treated as "PM" and midnight as "AM":

```
% date +'%H:%M %p'
08:01 am
```

"Under the hood", this calls [`strftime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime). See the man-page for more formatting options.

Answer (score 3):

It's depends on locale settings.

```
LC_TIME="C" date +%l%p
LC_TIME="C" date +'%l:%M %p'
```

Answer (score 2):

To get AM or PM as am or pm try this
date +%#p

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "+" formatting option of the date command. E.g.:

```
 > date +%l%p
-> 7PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date +"%P" capital P to display am or pm

Comment: Which bash version is this? This doesn't seem to work on Bash 3.2.